# Is this a correct non-technical description of mirror symmetry for Calabi-Yau manifolds arising from string theory?

Tags: string-theory, renormalization, conformal-field-theory, calabi-yau, mirror-symmetry

In string theory there are physical reasons why the space we live in must locally be the product of Minkowski space with a Calabi-Yau manifold. The general theory doesn't say which Calabi-Yau manifold. However, different Calabi-Yau manifolds give rise to different physics. In fact, Gepner devised a way to obtain a fully determined conformal field theory from a given Calabi-Yau manifold. It can already be seen from his construction that some Calabi-Yau manifolds give rise to the same CFT.

In the other direction Greene-Vafa-Warner managed to create a Calabi-Yau manifold starting from a CFT. After applying some symmetry to the Lagrangian you obtain a *different* Calabi-Yau manifold giving rise to the *same* CFT. These manifolds are generally not even topologically equivalent, but they do reflect each other's geometrical structure, most notably by an interchange of the non-trivial hodge numbers, in a way that was not at all anticipated on purely mathematical grounds.

Is this more or less accurate? And can anyone say something more about the CFT's that are being considered? Are they the theories that are obtained when we follow the renormalization group flow to a fixed point in which only the massless states survive? I would greatly appreciate an answer that is precise but not overly technical, to give me an intuition that can help me read more technical accounts.

Thanks!

Comment: The CFTs are two-dimensional and describe the embedding of the string in the CY, i.e. the bosonic fields of the CFT correspond to the different directions in the CY geometry that the string can oscillate.

Comment: @MitchellPorter Thanks. Does that mean that the CFT is a field theory on these surfaces (which I suppose are world sheets of strings)?

Comment: "the different directions in the CY geometry that the string can oscillate": does that mean that they take their values in the normal bundle to the tangent bundle of the embedded surface in the tangent bundle of the CY?

Comment: The bosonic part of the CFT is basically a position vector for the string worldsheet in the CY... But the CFT is more fundamental than the CY. Perturbative string theory is the sum over Riemann surfaces for this CFT, and the CY emerges from that.

Comment: @MitchellPorter Does this also mean that rather than a single CFT, we have a CFT on each possible world sheet embedded in the CY (or in the full 10D space)?

Comment: Given a specific CY, it is always the same CFT. Each possible string trajectory in (4d space x CY) corresponds to an equivalence class of bosonic field configurations on the worldsheet. Again, the 'worldsheet bosonic fields' are the spacetime coordinates of the CY.

Comment: Each point on the string has a 10d position vector; the components of the position vector are the values of the bosonic fields in the worldsheet CFT at that point on the string.

Comment: @MitchellPorter Thanks for taking the time to answer all my questions (feel free to stop answering if it is too much, I won't be offended). If I understand well, our base space is an abstract world sheet, and some of the fields on it actually describe how it is embedded in the CY. Those world sheets may also have different topologies though. Since it is still the same CFT, does that mean that our CFT actually lives on a (topological) plane that is mapped onto an embedded Riemann surface in a way prescribed by the 10D field?

Comment: This is all in the context of perturbative string theory. It is an S-matrix theory, so the basic quantities are amplitudes for going from one set of asymptotic states to another, and these amplitudes are obtained by sums over string histories that can be classified according to number of topological 'handles'. Each such history is conformally equivalent to a CFT configuration on a Riemann surface of genus equal to the number of handles in the space-time picture... This should be in any string theory textbook.